# XSLT - Select one node out of multiple. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value in 'cast as' expression

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT, but I'm making progress on learning. Can someone help me with the error I'm getting?-A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value in 'cast as' expression.

I basically have multiple instances and I only need to select one. The first condition is if the variable (date) is equal to the Period start Date and Period End date, then select that particular payment date. If not, then find the payment date where it falls within the Period start Date and Period End date. Otherwise, it is "unknown". For this example, I set the variable transdate to 2017-02-13, so I would like just the 2017-02-13 Payment date.

This is the sample XSLT before and transformation:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>1234567</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Current_Period/>
        <wd:Current_Period/>
        <wd:Current_Period/>
        <wd:Current_Period>
            <wd:Payment_Date>2017-02-09-08:00</wd:Payment_Date>
            <wd:End_Date>2017-02-12-08:00</wd:End_Date>
            <wd:Start_Date>2017-01-30-08:00</wd:Start_Date>
        </wd:Current_Period>
        <wd:Current_Period>
            <wd:Payment_Date>2017-02-13-08:00</wd:Payment_Date>
            <wd:End_Date>2017-02-13-08:00</wd:End_Date>
            <wd:Start_Date>2017-02-13-08:00</wd:Start_Date>
        </wd:Current_Period>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

This is my current transformation XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs wd">

    <xsl:variable name="var.input.trans.date"><xsl:value-of select="'2017-02-13'"/></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Record>
            <Employee_ID><xsl:value-of select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Employee_ID"/></Employee_ID>
                <xsl:variable name="transDate" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="$var.input.trans.date"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="(xs:date($transDate) = xs:date(/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Current_Period/substring(wd:Start_Date,1,10))) and (xs:date($transDate) = xs:date(/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Current_Period/substring(wd:End_Date,1,10))) "> 
                            <Payment_Date><xsl:value-of select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Current_Period/substring(wd:Payment_Date,1,10)"/></Payment_Date>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="(xs:date($transDate) &gt;= xs:date(/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Current_Period/substring(wd:Start_Date,1,10))) and (xs:date($transDate) &lt;= xs:date(/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Current_Period/substring(wd:End_Date,1,10))) "> 
                            <Payment_Date><xsl:value-of select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Current_Period/substring(wd:Payment_Date,1,10)"/></Payment_Date>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <Payment_Date><xsl:text>Unknown</xsl:text></Payment_Date>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I need as output for this particular instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record>
    <Employee_ID>1234567</Employee_ID>
    <Payment_Date>2017-02-13</Payment_Date>
</Record>
```

Comment: Instead of `xs:date(a/b/c/substring(.))`, do `a/b/c/xs:date(substring(.))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this expression...

```
xs:date(/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Current_Period/substring(wd:Start_Date,1,10)))
```

The xpath within this matches more than one element (It will return all start dates), and `xs:date` only wants one value to work on.

Try this XSLT instead. I've rejigged the template to match `wd:Report_Entry` and simplified the xpaths to be relative to that (because this then allows it to work with multiple `wd:Report_Entry` elements).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs wd">

    <xsl:variable name="var.input.trans.date"><xsl:value-of select="'2017-02-13'"/></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <Record>
            <Employee_ID><xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_ID"/></Employee_ID>
            <xsl:variable name="transDate" select="xs:date($var.input.trans.date)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="exactmatch" select="wd:Current_Period[wd:Start_Date and wd:End_Date and $transDate = xs:date(substring(wd:Start_Date, 1, 10)) and $transDate = xs:date(substring(wd:End_Date, 1, 10))]" />
            <xsl:variable name="period" select="wd:Current_Period[wd:Start_Date and wd:End_Date and $transDate ge xs:date(substring(wd:Start_Date, 1, 10)) and $transDate le xs:date(substring(wd:End_Date, 1, 10))]" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="exactmatch"> 
                    <Payment_Date><xsl:value-of select="substring($exactmatch/wd:Payment_Date, 1, 10)"/></Payment_Date>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$period"> 
                    <Payment_Date><xsl:value-of select="substring($period/wd:Payment_Date, 1, 10)"/></Payment_Date>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <Payment_Date><xsl:text>Unknown</xsl:text></Payment_Date>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Depending on your date, maybe the "exact" match is not need. After all, if it matches the start and end date, it also fulfils the logic of being greater than equal the start date, and less than equal the end date.

Try this too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs wd">

    <xsl:variable name="var.input.trans.date"><xsl:value-of select="'2017-02-13'"/></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <Record>
            <Employee_ID><xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_ID"/></Employee_ID>
            <xsl:variable name="transDate" select="xs:date($var.input.trans.date)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="period" select="wd:Current_Period[wd:Start_Date and wd:End_Date and $transDate ge xs:date(substring(wd:Start_Date, 1, 10)) and $transDate le xs:date(substring(wd:End_Date, 1, 10))]" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$period"> 
                    <Payment_Date><xsl:value-of select="substring($period/wd:Payment_Date, 1, 10)"/></Payment_Date>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <Payment_Date><xsl:text>Unknown</xsl:text></Payment_Date>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you very much for the solution and the clear explanation!